# Cannot import torchvision in Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-imaging-library, torchvision

I'm trying to go through a [simple neural networking tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py) on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine and run into this error when trying to import the `torchvision` module:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torchvision
  File "/home/drubbels/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from torchvision import datasets
  File "/home/drubbels/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .fakedata import FakeData
  File "/home/drubbels/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/fakedata.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import transforms
  File "/home/drubbels/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .transforms import *
  File "/home/drubbels/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import functional as F
  File "/home/drubbels/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, PILLOW_VERSION
ImportError: cannot import name 'PILLOW_VERSION' from 'PIL' (/home/drubbels/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

I've previously run into a similar `PIL`-related error when trying to display images in Open CV with Python, and was unable to resolve it then.

I know that both cases (this tutorial and the Open CV program) should have worked fine in principle, because I've previously done both with no problems on a Windows 8.1 machine (which I now no longer have access to). I have also run into the exact same problem with importing `torchvision` on *another* Ubuntu machine, so I don't think it's some weird quirk of my computer in particular. Therefore, I believe the problem is Linux-related.

I have already reinstalled `Pillow`, which didn't help.

EDIT: everything is installed with conda. I don't imagine there could be much wrong with the environment - I did a fresh install of Anaconda this morning.

Comment: How did you install the package? Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: I'm using conda for everything.

Comment: What packages are in your environment, how did you install them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this.

```
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/CHANGES.rst
```

The PILLOW_VERSION definition has been removed after 7.0.0 of Pillow.

So installing an old version Pillow will help.

```
pip install 'pillow<7.0.0'
```

or

```
pip3 install 'pillow<7.0.0'
```

If you are using conda.

```
conda uninstall pillow
conda install pillow=6.1
```

Comment: OP seems to be using Conda, so using pip is likely not the best idea here.

Comment: I am indeed using conda and not pip. I have no real experience installing particular version numbers of things, but I'm guessing I could probably do this in conda as well?

Comment: I just did `conda uninstall pillow` and then `conda install pillow=6.1` (I also had to reinstall torchvision with `conda install torchvision`, because it got removed with pillow). It's working like a charm now!

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it did solve my issue almost immediately, even if it wasn't technically correct for my situation. Of course, you could maybe edit to include a conda version, just to stop some future conda user who stumbles across the answer from doing ill-advised things with pip.